# Get sub menu items for each menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to get menu items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div.MenuItem a").each(function () {

    var children = $(this).children();

    alert(children.length);
});
```

from this script I need to get each children for the menu item. But here it always give me length as 1 even I have many sub items for the menu Item.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: you can use .child()

Comment: Are they really children of the <a> tag?

Comment: Show us please your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do?

```
$("div.MenuItem").parent().find( "div.MenuItem" ).length;
```

otherwise you are basically counting one menu item and a time

Answer (score 1):

You should get the childrens from the parent :

```
$(this).parent().children();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using a menu structure such as:

```
<div id="divMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Menu1Sub1</a></li>
                <li><a>Menu1Sub2</a></li>
                <li><a>Menu1Sub3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You would need:

```
$("#divMenu > ul > li > a").each(function () {

    var children = $(this).next('ul').children();

    alert(children.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo for you..same as you did

```js
$("div.MenuItem").each(function() {
  var children = $(this).children();
  alert(children.length);
});
```

```html
<div class="MenuItem">
  <a>j</a>
  <a>d</a>
  <a>c</a>
  <a>a</a>

</div>
```